# Why does wrapping a call to [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable not work in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell

I created this function:

```
function setUserEnvVar ([string]$varName, [string]$varValue)
{
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($varName, $varValue, "User")
}
```

I used varName and varValue to make sure I do not get into conflict with any PowerShell built-in variables that I might not be aware of right now.
When I call it using

```
setUserEnvVar("hi", "lo")
```

nothing happens.

I checked for the user environment variables going through the windows GUI. I know that you have to reload PowerShell to see changes in the environment variables.

But when I directly use

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("hi", "lo", "User")
```

everything works as expected.

In contrast this function work just fine:

```
function getUserEnvVar ([string]$Name)
{
  [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($Name, "User")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell does not use commas or parentheses in the argument list. Invoke the function like this:

```
setUserEnvVar "hi" "lo"
```

What is happening is that you are passing a string array as the first argument and nothing as the second argument. Powershell the coerces the string array into a string (as "hi lo" in your example). Then, since the variable value is null, `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` is actually deleting any existing variable with that name.

Comment: Yes! Of course! Thank you! It's not that I didn't know that, but - man I just couldn't see it.